# Cannot install RVM in macOS without Ruby, cannot upgrade Ruby without RVM

Tags: ruby, macos, command-line, command, rvm

My current version of Ruby is:

```
$ ruby -v 
ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
```

I need a more current version of Ruby so I tried to install it, however, I do not have RVM installed:

```
$ rvm
-bash: rvm: command not found
```

In order to install RVM, I went to https://rvm.io and followed the instructions. However, on the second command, I got the following:

```
$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/1.29.4.tar.gz
Downloading     
https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.29.4/1.29.4.tar.gz.asc
gpg: Signature made Sun  1 Jul 20:41:26 2018 BST
gpg:                using RSA key 62C9E5F4DA300D94AC36166BE206C29FBF04FF17
gpg: Good signature from "Michal Papis (RVM signing) <mpapis@gmail.com>" [unknown]
gpg:                 aka "Michal Papis <michal.papis@toptal.com>" [unknown]
gpg:                 aka "[jpeg image of size 5015]" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 409B 6B17 96C2 7546 2A17  0311 3804 BB82 D39D C0E3
Subkey fingerprint: 62C9 E5F4 DA30 0D94 AC36  166B E206 C29F BF04 FF17
GPG verified '/Users/me/.rvm/archives/rvm-1.29.4.tgz'
Upgrading the RVM installation in /Users/me/.rvm/
RVM PATH line found in /Users/me/.mkshrc /Users/me/.profile /Users/me/.bashrc /Users/me/.zshrc.
RVM sourcing line found in /Users/me/.profile /Users/me/.bash_profile /Users/me/.zlogin.
./scripts/functions/support: line 559: 65301 Abort trap: 6         "$ruby_path" -rrbconfig -e '\
File.open("'"$config_path"'","w") { |file|
  RbConfig::CONFIG.sort.each{|key,value|
    file.write("#{key.gsub(/\.|-/,"_")}=\"#    {value.to_s.gsub("$","\\$")}\"\n")
  }
}   
' > /dev/null 2>&1
Can not save config data for ruby: 'ruby-2.5.1', most likely it is broken installation and you can:
- try fix it: 'rvm reinstall ruby-2.5.1', OR:
- remove  it: 'rvm uninstall ruby-2.5.1 --gems'
Upgrade of RVM in /Users/me/.rvm/ is complete.
```

However, RVM was not installed or upgraded, as I am still getting:

```
$ rvm reload
-bash: rvm: command not found
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be? I know I can upgrade Ruby without RVM but I would prefer not to.

Comment: Might be more appropriate on https://apple.stackexchange.com . Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to type:

```
$ source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Then to upgrade ruby

```
rvm reinstall ruby-2.5.1
```

So I now have

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin16]
```